# How to convert a 'string pointer' to a string in Golang?

Tags: string, pointers, go, type-conversion

Is it possible to get the string value from a pointer to a string?

I am using the [goopt package](https://github.com/droundy/goopt) to handle flag parsing and the package returns *string only. I want to use these values to call a function in a map.

**[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/1s0-d-GO-L)**

```
var strPointer = new(string)
*strPointer = "string"

functions := map[string]func() {
    "string": func(){
        fmt.Println("works")
    },
}  

//Do something to get the string value

functions[strPointerValue]()
```

returns

```
./prog.go:17:14: cannot use strPointer (type *string) 
as type string in map index
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Dereference the pointer:

```
strPointerValue := *strPointer
```

Comment: that's correct, however if the pointer string is `nil` you will have a runtime error

Comment: What would be a better solution then?

Comment: @ram4nd 
    if strPointer != nil {
        strPointerValue := *strPointer
    }

Answer (score 27):

A simple function that first checks if the string pointer is nil would prevent runtime errors:

```
func DerefString(s *string) string {
    if s != nil {
        return *s
    }

    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generic https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790458/1079543 :

```golang
func SafeDeref[T any](p *T) T {
    if p == nil {
        var v T
        return v
    }
    return *p
}
```